# vectorizing finding index of smallest value from the boundary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a little bit of complicated problem. I have two set of array, lets call the first array `possible_values` and call the second array as `boundary`. The first array shape is (n,) each value in the array is a `list` of possible values. The second array shape is (n,2), where the value is the (min_value, max_value).

What I want to get is the **smallest index** of `possible_values` that fulfill the conditions from the boundary: It must be bigger than `min_value`, but it must be smaller or equal to `max_value`. This is an example for my problem.

```
import numpy as np
possible_values = np.array([[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[0.3,0.5,0.7],[0.2,0.5,0.8]])
boundary = np.array([[0.1, 0.4], [0.2,0.7],[0.1,0.15]])
```

this will give me result:

```
array([2, 0, None])
```

however, this code is extremely slow. Any better recommendation? I have tried to look at `np.minimum.reduceat`, but i'm not sure how I can use it in this case. Thank you!

Comment: You have a `boundary` array and a `min_max` array in your example, but not a `possible_values` array. Your `boundary` array also has a weird shape/dtype; nothing like your text before suggests (instead, the `min_max` array looks more like your suggested boundary style array, with `n = 3`). Please make sure your example code is accurate and works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find good solution for this

```
def padding(arr, n):
    np.array([arr for i in range(0,n)]).T

possible_values = np.array([[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5[0.3,0.5,0.7,-1,-1,-1],[0.2,0.5,0.8,-1,-1,-1]])
boundary = np.array([[0.1, 0.4], [0.2,0.7],[0.1,0.15]])
start_pt = fast_tile_axis1(boundary[:,0], possible_values.shape[1])
end_pt = fast_tile_axis1(boundary[:,1], possible_values.shape[1])
is_within_range = (start_pt < possible_values) & (end_pt > 
possible_values)
np.where(np.any(is_within_range, axis=1), np.argmax(is_within_range,axis=1), -1)
```